# SubSonic inner join mystery

Tags: subsonic, inner-join

I've have 2 tables CampaignCoverage and Coverage

CampaignCoverage has a CoverageID column. Coverage has a column DateX.

Basically I've not specified in the code that CampaignCoverage.CoverageID = Coverage.ID like you would to in SQL. How does this work at all????!!!!

```
CampaignCoverageCollection campaignCoverages = 
    new Select()
        .From(Tables.CampaignCoverage)
        .InnerJoin(Tables.Coverage)                               
        .Where(Coverage.DateXColumn).IsGreaterThan(ucDateStart.DateTime)
        .And(Coverage.DateXColumn).IsLessThan(ucDateEnd.DateTime)
        .And(CampaignCoverage.CampaignIDColumn).IsEqualTo(campaign.Id)
        .ExecuteAsCollection<CampaignCoverageCollection>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not specified that CampaignCoverage.CoverageID is a foreign key to Coverage.ID (I think that is what you are trying to say), then getting rid of the join should do the trick.  i.e. Remove

```
.InnerJoin(Tables.Coverage)
```

That said, you probably do want to make a CampaignCoverage.CoverageID a foreign key to Coverage.ID.  After you do that, you can get rid of the IsEqualTo clause.  i.e. Remove

```
.And(CampaignCoverage.CampaignIDColumn).IsEqualTo(campaign.Id)
```